# WordPress author page description break line /new row

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a custom plugin that makes my Biographical Info editor look like normal editor.
However the only problem is that there are no line breaks / new rows on front end when making them in backend and i have no idea where the problem is.

Here is part of codes from the plugin

```
<?php $author_id =  $wp_query->queried_object->ID; ?>



function user_bio_visual_editor( $user ) {
    if (function_exists('wp_editor')):
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){ 
        $('#description').parents('tr').remove();
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="description"><?php _e('Biographical Info'); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <?php 
                $description = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'description', true);
                $editor_settings = array('media_buttons' => false);
                wp_editor( $description, 'description' , $editor_settings); 
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'user_bio_visual_editor');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'user_bio_visual_editor');
```

Here is part of the code from template

```
<?php if((get_the_author_meta('description', $author_id))!=""): ?>
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('description', $author_id),"<br>"; endif;?>
```

How do i make the line breaks/ new rows visible on front end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the function `wpautop`.

As an example:

```
<?php 
if((get_the_author_meta('description', $author_id))!=""):
    echo wpautop(get_the_author_meta('description', $author_id)),"<br>"; 
endif;
?>
```

Readmore: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop